# Gather all Values of Field in Collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB DB with each Collection in this form:

```
'id': '1',
'TopKey':{
    '4':[
        {'name':'name1', 
         'age':18, 
         'dimensions':
             [{'weight':125, 'height':72}], 
         'meals':
            [{'breakfast':2, 'lunch':7, 'dinner':7}]
         },
        {'name':'name2', 
         'age':21, 
         'dimensions':
             [{'weight':137, 'height':69}], 
         'meals':
            [{'breakfast':0, 'lunch':7, 'dinner':6}]
         }
        ],
    '5':[
        {'name':'name1', 
         'age':18, 
         'dimensions':
             [{'weight':130, 'height':72}], 
         'meals':
            [{'breakfast':5, 'lunch':7, 'dinner':7}]
         },
        {'name':'name2', 
         'age':21, 
         'dimensions':
             [{'weight':140, 'height':69}], 
         'meals':
            [{'breakfast':7, 'lunch':6, 'dinner':6}]
         }
        ]}
```

I would like to query this db and get a list of all `age` and `weight` values.

I've tried to query like this but it's not adaptable since the keys within `TopKey` can be many different sets of numbers (sometimes 0,1,2 and other times 4,5,8,9 for example)

```
a = db.collection_name.find({},{'TopKey.4.age'})
print(a[0])

> {'id': 1,
    'TopKey':{'4': [
        {'age':18},
        {'age':21}]}}
```

I would like a list of all `age` in all collections. I also tried using `distinct('TopKey.4.age')` but it only collects unique values in a list. I'm looking for something like `distinct()` in the way it returns values from the whole collection in original order.

Comment: Your "data" has countless mistakes. At least go to the trouble of checking it before posting.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I thought I had checked it but you're right there were many mistakes. All fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the record structure and you can use a `set` to keep track of the unique values:

```
records = db.collection_name.find({}, {'TopKey': 1})

ages = set()

for record in records:
    for k, v in record.get('TopKey').items():
        for item in v:
            ages.add(item.get('age'))

print(ages)
```

prints:

```
{18, 21}
```